# Building mariadb-connector-c library as a submodule

Tags: cmake, mariadb

I am trying to build mariadb client library as a submodule by using `add_subdirectory(external/mariadb-connector-c)` from my project. When I build standalone mariadb client, everything works fine, however this solution means that I have to link pre-built binaries directly. I would like to avoid this kind of two step build process, but when I try to run cmake from my project, I got a lot of errors related to mariadb plugins:

```
CMake Error at external/mariadb-connector-c/cmake/install_plugins.cmake:11 (INSTALL):
  INSTALL TARGETS given no LIBRARY DESTINATION for module target
  "client_ed25519".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  external/mariadb-connector-c/cmake/plugins.cmake:82 (INSTALL_PLUGIN)
  external/mariadb-connector-c/plugins/auth/CMakeLists.txt:54 (REGISTER_PLUGIN)
  external/mariadb-connector-c/plugins/CMakeLists.txt:7 (INCLUDE)
  external/mariadb-connector-c/CMakeLists.txt:403 (INCLUDE)
```

Here, `external/mariadb-connector-c` is registered as a git submodule inside of my project repository.
Is there any way to embed mariadb client library as a submodule to make it work by running CMake from my root project or do I have to build it as a standalone project?

Answer (score 1):

It does not work for mee too (linux, cmake-3.10)

I have to set at least `SET(INSTALL_PLUGIN x)` to avoid cmake errors.

Here is my minimal working example:

```cmake
# file CMakeLists.txt
PROJECT(my_connector_info)

SET(INSTALL_PLUGINDIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}) # needed by mariadb-connector-c
add_subdirectory(libs/mariadb-connector-c-3.1.10-src EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} my_connector_info.c)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} mariadbclient)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} SYSTEM PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/mariadb-connector-c-3.1.10-src/include)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} SYSTEM PRIVATE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libs/mariadb-connector-c-3.1.10-src/include)
```

```c
/* file my_connector_info.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main()
{
    printf("info: %s\n", mysql_get_client_info());    
    return 0; 
}
```

Here's how you build it:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -eux
(
    mkdir -p libs
    cd libs
    test -e mariadb-connector-c-3.1.10-src.tar.gz || wget https://dlm.mariadb.com/1157459/Connectors/c/connector-c-3.1.10/mariadb-connector-c-3.1.10-src.tar.gz
    test -d mariadb-connector-c-3.1.10-src || tar -xzf mariadb-connector-c-3.1.10-src.tar.gz
    cd -
)
mkdir -p build
cd build
cmake ..
make
./my_connector_info
```

output of my_connector_info:

```
info: 10.5.5
```